# Should i use left align or center align in webdesign?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, ux-designer, alignment

I know that center align text would not easy to read , because user should be find  where the next line text start.

But i find that more web use the center align in their design , and it look beautiful. so ,I want to know what situation should use left align or center align . 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: For what purpose? Headlines? Paragraphs? Longforms of text? Inside form fields? You'd need to provide lot more information to get meaningful answers.

Comment: Just like a landing page . One block container include heading ,secondary ,products name and some text what introduce products .

Comment: And i away found that text center aligned the image .

Comment: This feels too opinionated, there is no right or wrong answer to this, it depends on the rest of the design. Also, this will differ if you are international or not (some languages are right aligned). Maybe the question should focus more on the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the article [How to Use Centered Alignments: Tips and Examples](https://designshack.net/articles/layouts/how-to-use-centered-alignments-tips-and-examples/) the following recommendations are suggested :

> There’s nothing inherently bad about a centered alignment, you just
>   have to know how to properly yield one if you’re going to implement it
>   with any amount of success.
>
> The first thing you need to learn is when not to implement a centered
>   alignment. The answer here is pretty simple: when you have a lot of
>   content.
>
> It’s very important in any design to analyze your goals. If a
>   significant degree of readability is one of them, and it often should
>   be, then aesthetic appeal is often completely separate or even
>   directly at odds with this goal. The trick is to find the balance
>   between the two.
>
> One of the first places you can start to think about implementing a
>   completely centered layout is when you have very little content.
>
> Make sure that, if your entire layout is built on a centered
>   alignment, you have a very simple design with only a few items. Once
>   you start adding big blocks of text and lots of images, the centered
>   alignments starts looking messy. Also, try building a solid left,
>   justified or even right alignment for your page as a whole, then
>   experiment with selectively dropping in centered alignments in key
>   areas such as headlines. Finally, as a quick trick when you’re in a
>   jam, try wrapping center-aligned portions in a box that goes with the
>   flow of the rest of the page.

Answer (score 4):

Use **center align** for:

- Headings
- Bullet points (not always)
- Short messages with not more than 1 sentence.

This way the users won't be looking where the next line text starts because there is only 1 line of text.

**Use left/right align** for text with more than 1 line to assure best readability for long texts.

Answer (score 2):

You could use justified text for aesthetic purposes, as well.

Well, given that centre aligned text would be difficult to read, you could use it sparesly for some short paragraphs, e.g. introductory paragraphs following a heading.

Comment: I would not suggest "Justify" as it's not a best practice from the following references, http://designforhackers.com/blog/never-justify-type-on-the-web/ https://www.castlegateit.co.uk/2013/09/can-justified-text-be-justifed-for-the-web/ https://dmjcomputerservices.com/blog/why-you-shouldnt-align-html-justify/

Comment: I prefer justified texts, especially when reading longer texts. Text that isn't properly aligned at both sides just makes me nervous. its feels strange. I hate reading articles with left aligned texts where the text doesn't align properly on the right. The sources you cite can be easily refuted - the first claim is that its looks "messy" inside the text. this is simply not true, read any book, magazine or paper. "The tech on the web isn't ready". Have to disagree. "Justified text is harder to read". On the contary. Its *much* less strenous. "Its bad typograhpy". tell that any book publisher.